# How to use assertRaisesRegex in this situation?

Tags: python, assertraises

I'm trying to use `assertRaisesRegex` (from the unittest module) to ensure that an exception (from our C++ backend) is raised when performing the following assignment:

```
a[:, 0] = b[:, 0]
```

`a` and `b` here are custom types defined in our backend.

In the cases I've seen `assertRaisesRegex` used, a function along with its arguments is passed into `assertRaisesRegex`, but in this case I need to test that the exception is raised during the above assignment. How can I best do that without having to write an additional function to do the assignment?

Comment: If you're talking about [`assertRaisesRegex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegex) from the `unittest` module, then you can use the object returned by it as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) in a [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) that wraps that assignemnt

Comment: @Brian I'll take a look. I saw in our codebase that someone did the following for a different situation:
`self.assertRaisesRegex(RuntimeError, "divisor must be not zero",
                               lambda: obj.func(args))`. Could I wrap the equality assignment in a lambda like what this person did? I'm actually not sure why the lambda keyword was needed in this situation

Comment: Lambda bodies can't include statements (like assignments) in Python; they can only have a single expression.  If you want to test one or more statements that aren't part of an existing callable, a `with` statement would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import unittest


class SomeSpecificError(Exception):
    pass


class OtherError(Exception):
    pass


class FakeData:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        raise SomeSpecificError(f"can't get slice {key!r}")


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        a = FakeData()
        b = FakeData()

        with self.assertRaisesRegex(SomeSpecificError, "can't get slice"):
            a[:, 0] = b[:, 0]
        # passes

        with self.assertRaisesRegex(SomeSpecificError, "something something"):  #
            a[:, 0] = b[:, 0]
        # fails:
        # AssertionError: "something something" does not match "can't get slice (slice(None, None, None), 0)"

        with self.assertRaisesRegex(OtherError, "something something"):  #
            "no exception raised in this block"
        # fails:
        # AssertionError: OtherError not raised
```

Obviously, substitute my `FakeData` with your own actual class, mine is for testing (like a mock).

Comment: The second argument (the error string) only has to partially match the error string produced by SomeSpecificError right? That seems to be how it's working for me in practice

Comment: @user5965026 the [doc for `unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegex) says : ` regex may be a regular expression object or a string containing a regular expression suitable for use by `[`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). So it may match anywhere in the exception representation's string. You can also use **real** regex syntax (i.e. `[]|\d`...) in the second argument, that's left to you.